# AngularJS / CSS-Selectors - Form Validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-selectors

Simple question:

Why is it that the `summary` class can directly be appended to the `<span>` element but not the `ng-classes` to the `<form>` tag?

Is it because the `ng-classes` are later generated during runtime? What are the guidelines?

### CSS:

[image]

### HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is not how you use ng-class. Instead do this:

```
<span class="summary" ng-class="{ 'ng-valid': myForm.$valid, 'ng-invalid': !myForm.$valid }">...</span>
```

If you want to do it the way you have it do it like this:

```
<span class="summary {{ myForm.$valid ? 'ng-valid' : 'ng-invalid' }}">...</span>
```

Next time you need help on stackoverflow, please paste the code instead of images. Would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Isn't this a matter of taste? According to my book, this is how its supposed to be done - speaking for myself, I visually prefer the syntax from the book (in case there aren't any other benefits). Anyway, the orginal question was related to the extra space between the `form ng-invalid.ng-dirty` compared to `span.summary.ng-invalid` css selector part.